# How to Add a tooltip in Radio Buttons when checked in newForm.aspx page

Tags: 2013, list, jquery

I have custom list with a field type of radio buttons with 4 choices. I want to be able to show a box on right hand side when each radio button is checked .How do i do that?
So far i was able to target id of the input field

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
{

var x= document.getElementById('Site_x0020_Type_084a7e58-b428-4e43-98b6-2a7d10bc8941_$RadioButtonChoiceField0');
if(x.checked=true)

{
alert("done");

$(".ms-RadioText").append('<p>Test description</p>');
}    
});
</script>
```

This Script adds the paragraph under the choice, but in all choices. I think that is because i am targetting the class which all of those elements share.

What do i do to display the box on right when choice is selected.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

I am assuming you want to show box as user click on any of the radio button having style set to `ms-RadioText`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="box" style="width:10px;height:10px;border:1px solid red;display:none;"></div>');
        $('input[id^="Site_x0020_Type_084a7e58-b428-4e43-98b6-2a7d10bc8941_$RadioButtonChoiceField"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var pos = $(this).position();
            var width = $(this).outerWidth();

            //show the menu directly over the placeholder
            $("#box").css({
                position: "absolute",
                top: pos.top+3 + "px",
                left: (pos.left + 20) + "px"
            }).show();
        }         
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank You for the script Amal, but my form is not responding to if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var pos = $(this).position();
            var width = $(this).outerWidth();

            //show the menu directly over the placeholder
            $("#box").css({
                position: "absolute",
                top: pos.top+3 + "px",
                left: (pos.left + 20) + "px"
            }).show();

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: version number is  1.11.2

Comment: Is there any JavaScript error on the console? Can you add few alert message and make sure the click event is firing?

Comment: Alert only fires off after $('.ms-RadioText').click(function(){
});      after i add if condition to check the checked value it does not respond. no jquery error.

Comment: Try this condition `if($(this).prop('checked'))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18268/discussion-between-amal-hashim-and-allegro-octopus).

Comment: Amal if($(this).prop('checked')) didnt work either.

Comment: `if($(this).attr('checked'))`

Comment: Didnt work either, i am using content editor webpart in the newitems form, does that make any diffrence

Comment: No i found the issue.. the jquery selector was wrong. check updated answer

Comment: Yup that worked , great, now how do i add text and properly position that tooltip, it is displaying on top of the screen.

Comment: You can adjust it using `$("#box").css`. If you want to add text inside the box, then use `$("#box").html('SomeText')`

Comment: How would i populate different text for different radio box is checked.

Comment: `var text = "text to display";$("#box").html(text);` for each click based on your logic change the `var text` value

Comment: Amal, when the script loads i want the box to be populated for the first check box. How do i make that work. I tageted that elements id and attached load() but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

here is my mark up taken from IE developer tool.First input control is checked as default in the form.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the NewForm in SharePoint Designer, and add an html select element. In this select, each option will correspond to one of your radio button choice. You will have to use jQuery to update your radio button choices. The soltion should resemble to the one that's described in this post: http://sharepointhowtwo.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-add-tooltip-to-sharepoint-choice_27.html.

Regards

Comment: i tried implementing it. it didnt work.